# How to give path in SiriusObfuscator?

Tags: ios, swift, obfuscation

1) I downlaoded SiriusObfuscator tool with this link https://github.com/Polidea/SiriusObfuscator/releases/tag/v0.5.0. 
2)  Tried to run this command 
`` $ bin/sirius -projectrootpath <path-to-xcode-project> -obfuscatedproject `<path-for-obfuscated-project>` [-namemappingstrategy <name-mapping-strategy>] [-keepintermediates] [-inplace] [-verbose] ``
path for project is : '/Users/xxx/Library/yyy/MyApp'
I want obfuscated project should be in : '/Users/xxx/Library/yyy'

I am confused how to give path in the above command. I tried like

```
   $ bin/sirius -projectrootpath '/Users/xxx/Library/yyy/MyApp' -obfuscatedproject '/Users/xxx/Library/yyy'
```

It says `/Users/xxx/Library/yyy` is not a directory.How to give a path?Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: issue resolved? @Amutha Priya